# Error while using use in the class

Tags: php, composer-php

**index.php**

/*type autoload:psr-4 with namespace for dir controller*/

```
require_once "app/start.php";
$a=new App\controller\create();
$a->xadd();
```

**composer.json**

The contents of the index file are as follows

```
{
    "require": {

    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "config.php"
        ],
        "classmap": [
            "app/models"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\":"app"

        }
    }
}
```

**create.php**

The contents of the create.php file are as follows

```
<?php
namespace App\controller;
use App\controller\port\xredis as ssff;
class create extends ssff{
    function xadd()
    {
        xlocalhost();
        echo("create a new post");
    }
    function xremove(){
        echo "create a remove post";
    }
}
```

**port.php**

The contents of the port.php file are as follows

```
<?php
namespace App\controller\port;
 class xredis{
     public function xlocalhost()
     {
         echo "host ip 127.0.0.1";
     }
     public function xport()
     {
         echo "port is 33767";
     }
 }
?>
```

The error message below shows

> Fatal error: Class 'App\controller\port\xredis' not found in
>   C:\laragon\www\php\autoload-class\app\controller\create.php on line 4

Answer (score 0):

Rename `port.php` to `xredis.php` if the file is found within `App\controller\port`.

Otherwise rename your class to `port` and remove `port` from the namespace, if the file is found within `App\controller`. Examples below.

#### App\controller\port.php

```
namespace App\controller;

class port { /** ... */ }
```

#### App\controller\port\xredis.php

```
namespace App\controller\port;

class xredis { /** ... */ }
```

PSR-4 autoloading expects the filename to match the class name.

> The terminating class name corresponds to a file name ending in .php. The file name MUST match the case of the terminating class name.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/